# ngrx observable data took from a ngrx selector is NOT getting updated outside subscribe if the value in REDUX is getting updated from other component

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, selector, store

i have an below in my typescript (simplified component) file

```
public param_getting_updated_inHTML: number = 0;
public param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML: number = 0;

ngOnInit(): void {
      this.store.select(selectorName).subscribe(
      (data) => { 
        this.param_getting_updated_inHTML= data;
      }
    );

    this.param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML= this.param_getting_updated_inHTML+ 100;
}
```

and my (simplified) HTML is as below

```
<div> {{param_getting_updated_inHTML}}  </div> // this is getting updated properly if the value is changed from other place
<div> {{param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML}}  </div> // (err) This is not getting updated
```

Comment: Do you mean that param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML shows as 0 or 100 in template?

Comment: this line `this.param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML= this.param_getting_updated_inHTML+ 100;` will only be run once as its not part of the subscribe code gettign the updated value form the store `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
this.param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML = this.param_getting_updated_inHTML+ 100;
```

is outside of the subscription that changes the `param_getting_updated_inHTML` var, so it will certainly be triggered before the subscription returns the value and updates the `param_getting_updated_inHTML` var. Thus, since the both vars are initialized with value of 0, the `param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML` will just add 100 to 0, while the template will display `param_getting_updated_inHTML` as some value other than 0 as soon as the subscription returns.

In other words, if you put

```
this.param_NOT_getting_updated_inHTML = this.param_getting_updated_inHTML+ 100;
```

under the subscription - when `param_getting_updated_inHTML` actually gets its value from the store - it will work as expected.